# SolrJ 8.11.1 upgrade - Invalid version (expected 2, but 31) or the data in not in 'javabin' format

Tags: java, windows, solr, solrj

I am in the process of upgrading my application from Solr 8.7.0 to Solr 8.11.1.  Both the server and solr-solrj-8.11.1.jar have been updated to the same version.  Solr servers are on RHEL 7. When I run my client app in JBoss 7 on Windows, all of the SolrJ calls fail with:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid version (expected 2, but 31) or the data in not in 'javabin' format
   at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec._init(JavaBinCodec.java:213)
   at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.initRead(JavaBinCodec.java:202)
   at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:195)
   at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BinaryResponseParser.processResponse(BinaryResponseParser.java:51)
   at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:641)
   ... 94 more
```

The same application runs just fine when deployed to a RHEL 7 JBoss, it is only on Windows that it fails. The Windows application has been working with no issues until this upgrade.

Any ideas?

Windows Java version java version "1.8.0_251"
Server Java version "1.8.0_311"

Comment: did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue as above, in case anyone had the same problem as us.
We migrated from 8.3.0 to 8.11.2.

Our http client was set up to always add a "Accept: gzip" header without any implementation that would un-gzip a response.
8.3.0 did not use gzip and just returned javabin not-gzipped, so no problem there.
8.11.2 does return gzip. That lead to the above exception.

The exception is basically solrj telling you that it is unable to parse the payload response (because it is gzipped, but expects plain javabin).